# Epoch/UNIX Time Conversion JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm working with an API which has the following response:

```
{
  dt: 1474664400,
  temp: {
   day: 51.93,
   min: 46.62,
   max: 53.53,
   night: 46.62,
   eve: 51.42,
   morn: 50.02
},
```

I've assigned the `dt` value to a variable called `${dateTime}` however I need to convert that date into a readable format. I've tried all sorts of approaches, such as the following but the output is not correct, I'm getting it dated back to 1970.

```
<jsp:useBean id="dateObject" class="java.util.Date" />
<jsp:setProperty name="dateObject" property="time" value="${dateTime}" />

<fmt:formatDate value="${dateObject}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

Is there a better approach to this? I would like to reference the result of the conversion within a variable but I'm unsure how I'd go about this.

Comment: Define "not correct".

Comment: I get a time stamp that dates back to 1970 lol

Comment: Then you're not passing in the number you think you are; you're either giving it zero or null or something; that is the epoch from which timestamps are based.

Comment: I'm unsure as to where my code is going wrong then, or if there's a better approach. The ${dateTime} variable holds the `dt` API response as I'm able to print it.

Comment: The better approach is to do this work on the server side instead of loading up the view layer with logic. But if you're getting time 0 (`January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`) then you're not setting it to what you think you are. I'm not sure what you mean by the "dt object`; `dt` is contained *within* an object.

Comment: Typo, meant to say value. All I know is that `${dateTime}` holds the correct date value, and when I pass it through the code above it outputs a date from 1970. I don't know if using a scriptlet would be better or not.

Comment: Java timestamp is _milliseconds_ since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, Unix is _seconds_ so you need to multiply it by 1000.

Comment: Oh right, forgot that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong input number. Please try the following JSP.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<jsp:useBean id="dateObject" class="java.util.Date" />
now is ${dateObject.time} 
and that is <fmt:formatDate value="${dateObject}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" /><br/>
<jsp:setProperty name="dateObject" property="time" value="${1474664400}" />
Your number is 1474664400 and that is 
<fmt:formatDate value="${dateObject}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

The output is 
now is 1474686578966 and that is 23/09/2016
Your number is 1474664400 and that is 17/01/1970